# Is it possible to reliably create a first-one-wins custom dimension in GA?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm using analytics.js and Google tag manager to track my website.

Given that a custom dimension of scope session is 'last value wins' I am wondering if it is possible to have a 'first value wins' dimension in GA?

Is it possible, or a very bad idea, for example, to sync up my own custom cookie value with the expiration time of the user's GA analytics session?

According to [this post](http://searchengineland.com/update-made-to-definition-of-a-google-analytics-session-89300)

> Google Analytics will end a session when:
>   1. Greater than 30 minutes have elapsed between pageviews for a single user
>   2. At the end of a day
>   3. When any campaign information for the user changes. Campaign information includes: utm_source, utm_medium, utm_term, utm_content, utm_id, utm_campaign and auto-tagging from AdWords (gclid)

I want to know what section of the site my users enter on or visit first, and not reset that if they visit another section before leaving. I want that set when the user first sets that custom dimension (that is, only if it's not set yet during the session). I could attempt to implement my own logic that mirrors the above expiration scenarios, but that could get ugly and I'd rather not reinvent the wheel.

I was thinking it would be cool if you could ask the tracker object on the page what its session timeout should be for syncing with it. The cookie itself expires in 2 years and the logic it uses to determine whether a session is new or not is obfuscated.

Comment: +1. I really really miss something like _getVisitorCustomVar() from ga.js in Universal Analytics (although I guess for most practical purposes a session cookie to mark if the dimension is set would be good enough if you are dealing with session scope dimensions). It certainly would be possible to synch (you'd do that in a hit callback since GA updates its cookie on interaction calls) but it sounds like a major PITA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

phpguru,

What you could do is to **create two custom dimensions and to achieve "first value wins" dimension simply set it only once per session.** This could be easily done with Google Tag Manager using session cookies (see [this post with detailed how-to instructions](http://www.simoahava.com/analytics/universal-analytics-fire-script-just-per-session/)).

Then you can have "regular" custom dimension with last value wins, if needed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This link is extremely helpful, Petr, thank you! It does, however, also confirm my suspicion that you cannot easily sync your own cookie with GA's cookie; only approximate it.

Comment: True, but am afraid there is no better solution yet and nothing will ever be 100% accurate. phpguru - would you mind accepting my answer if it helped...?

Comment: The answer is "There is currently no way to sync with GA's session". If you edit your answer to reflect that may work as a close approximation in some cases, I will accept it.

Comment: phpguru, thinking about this, I don't see the implied issue. If you need to make sure the value gets send only once during a visit, I don't see it as that big of a risk if there is a slight difference in expiration between "your" and GA cookie (unless you have a website that has lots of returning traffic multiple times a day).

Comment: My website has lots of returning traffic, and lots of simultaneous campaigns. To be accurate I need a way to sync with GA's session timeout. Until they expose a way to do that in the ga( ) object, I can only be close enough with the approximately similar expiry I put on my cookie. They may not be able to - meaning, it's probably calculated at night during analysis.